# Renaming files in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to rename a file in phonegap, having followed their documentation. However the operation fails with "error code 1":

```
this.rename_file = function(current_name, current_dir, new_name, success_callback) {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {

        fileSystem.root.getFile(current_dir + current_name, null, function (file_entry) {
            fileSystem.root.getDirectory(current_dir, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function (dir_entry) {
                alert(current_dir + current_name);
                parent_entry = new DirectoryEntry(current_name, current_dir + current_name);

                file_entry.moveTo(parent_entry, new_name, function () {
                    alert(new_name)
                    success_callback();

                }, rename_fail);
            }, rename_fail);
        }, rename_fail);

    }, rename_fail);

    function rename_fail(error) { 
         alert("Error renaming file " + error.code); 
    } 
};
```

Any ideas as to what the problem could be? Files exist, paths are correct.

Comment: According to [File plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md) the error code 1 stands for _Not found_ error. So how do you know the paths are right?

Comment: Using a file browser app on Android.

Comment: Please check if file_entry is valid in your code snippet. And let me know how it goes. Also check if current_dir + current_name makes valid URI... as final slash can be missing in current_dir variable @Ben

Comment: Thanks devmaniac. The URI is valid: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/foo.png...

Comment: Also, file_entry is valid.